# Confusion related to derivation of the probability distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes

I was reading a paper where they showed that when $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ are two multidimensional variables

$$p(z_{nk}=1|\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Z}_{\neg nk})\propto p(\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{Z})p(z_{nk}=1|\mathbf{Z}_{\neg nk}).$$

I didn't get how this expression was obtained. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to follow from: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.